# Ajax Web-Api optional parameter null issue.

Tags: asp.net-web-api, bad-request, http-status-code-400

Ajax webapi when parameter is null or blank then 400 bad reuqsest occurs. solution needed asap.

```
http://{parenturl}/api/BuildTypeWebApi/GetBuildTypeList?CurrPage=1&PageSize=10&BuildTypeName=
```

here BuildTypeName is optional parameter when there is not search parameter passed how to reduce 400 error.

//controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetBuildTypeList(int CurrPage, int PageSize, string BuildTypeName = "")
{
}
```

here issue with only BuildType.

help some one.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the way the request is made. Either complete your request string by adding `=""` to the end, or leave out the `BuildTypeName` parameter when it is empty.

So you get either of these two cases:

`/api/BuildTypeWebApi/GetBuildTypeList?CurrPage=1&PageSize=10&BuildTypeName=""`

`/api/BuildTypeWebApi/GetBuildTypeList?CurrPage=1&PageSize=10`

This way, Web API actually knows what you want to do with the BuildTypeName parameter. In your case it was an incomplete request.